# How can i connect mysql to firebase?

Tags: android, mysql, android-notifications, magento2

I need notification in android when changes occur in db of mysql ,how can i do that ?,The db is connected to the magento and at the same time i need the db to be connected to android.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase will not help you achieve this. You need to develop your own mechanism to track changes in your MySQL Database. Firebase is a real-time database which can provide you this feature but you cannot use Firebase to detect a change that has been made in MySQL Database.

Comment: If I cannot achieve it using Firebase then how do i solve my issue ? I am new to android studio. I just want to send notification using android studio when there is a new record added in my Mysql database.

Comment: What can you do is to check your MySQL database for new rows, setting a trigger and every time a new row is inserted, send the notification using Firebase. Remember, this will work only with your own mechanism.

Comment: can u help me out with trigger function? thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know your code and i cannot code for you. I advices you how you can achieve that. What have you tried so far?

Comment: so far i have tried to connect my database with android studio and from that to firebase in order to create tokens. But it didn't work out.

Comment: The answer to your question was that there is no way to connect mysql to firebase. This issue is not related with the initial one. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: You're welcome. So, if you still think that my answer helped you in any, please consider accepting it. Thanks!